# jqGrid with virtual paging - clear grid without calling loadComplte

Tags: jqgrid

I have virtual paging tuned on my jqGrid (scroll = 1). I am doing a advanced server side search and when a search is found I want the data to be returned to the jqGrid. I want to clear the grid before I bind the new data. I have observed that when I call clearGridData function, it calls load complete. Is there a way to prevent loadComplete being called and clearing all rows in the grid before I bind the ones in which I found my search result?

Comment: You can try GridUnload() and then recreate the Grid. so if your container table is "somegrid" then

$("#somegrid").GridUnload();
$("#somegrid").jqGrid({...});

Comment: I am losing my colModel $("#someGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel") after I call reload...Why is this? Thanks for your previous answer

Comment: Is it possible to take a copy of all the options set for a jqGrid before GridUnload is called so its easy to reconstruct it?

Comment: Instead why not create a function that creates the jqGrid and call the same function again right after you call GridUnload.